# How to I make the speed of the motor of my robot decrease as it move

Tags: arduino, sensors

How to I make the speed of the motor of my robot decrease as it move

Currently, I have this lines of code (a part of a program) that will make the robot (1) drive forward for around 15 cm then (2) turn right if the distance detected by the ultrasonic sensor is greater than or equal to 16 cm. But if the distance detected by the ultrasonic sensor is lesser than or equal to 15, then the robot will turn left

```
if (distance >= 16) {
    motors.setLeftSpeed(100);
    motors.setRightSpeed(100);
    delay(1120);
    motors.setLeftSpeed(100);
    motors.setRightSpeed(-100);
    delay(1000);
  }

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
  if (distance <= 15) {
    motors.setLeftSpeed(-100);
    motors.setRightSpeed(100);
    delay(900);
  }
```

The output is shown in the video below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15KNkaCQL4SCeoPb0W4gIJdo2ZS64duqw/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xdu25uNSYzHre_tm5PPQLwrbo7n-ZC0U/view?usp=sharing

Now, I have this problem. The turns of the robot is not consistent. I am guessing it is because it *suddenly* stop and turn. So I think I should make the robot move/turn slowly first, then it will gradually pick up speed and will slow again.

```
if (distance >= 16) {
    for (int speed = 200; speed >= 0; speed--) {
      motors.setLeftSpeed(100);
      motors.setRightSpeed(100);
      delay(1120);
      motors.setLeftSpeed(100);
      motors.setRightSpeed(-100);
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  if (distance <= 15) {
    for (int speed = 200; speed >= 0; speed--) {
      motors.setLeftSpeed(-100);
      motors.setRightSpeed(100);
      delay(900);
    }
  }
```

That is part of the code I currently have, and the output is shown in the video below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L7IFHQImw6Pv01HHJSa8bsfrKYQUbhzr/view?usp=sharing

As you can see, the code doesnt work. Any tips on how can I fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how the for loops are written.

```
//this will create a loop, that has an iterator variable called speed.
//speed is initially set to 200
//then for each pass through the loop, it is decremented by 1
//the loop stops if "speed" gets to a value below 0
for (int speed = 200; speed >= 0; speed--) 
{
  //motor speeds are then set to a constant reference
  motors.setLeftSpeed(-100);
  motors.setRightSpeed(100);
  
  the constant speed is maintained for 900ms
  delay(900);
}
```

your for loop will continue to turn for 900ms * 200 iterations, without changing the speed...

what I think you wanted was something where the speed of the motors are changing on each loop, so here is an example of ramping up speed from 0 to 100:

```
//this will create a loop, that has an iterator variable called speed.
//speed is initially set to 0
//then for each pass through the loop, it is incremented by 1
//the loop stops if "speed" gets to a value below 0
for (int speed = 0; speed < 100; speed++) 
{
  //motor speeds are then set to run at at "speed"
  motors.setLeftSpeed(-1 * speed);
  motors.setRightSpeed(speed);
  
  the newspeed is maintained for some time, before we increase it further:
  delay(9);
}
```

this will give you a ramping time of 9ms * 100 loops = 900ms
and a start speed of 0, and end speed of 100.

however this means we are now turning at full speed, untill we slow down again, so we want a ramp going downwards:

```
for (int speed = 100; speed >= 0; speed--) 
{
  //motor speeds are then set to run at at "speed"
  motors.setLeftSpeed(-1 * speed);
  motors.setRightSpeed(speed);
  
  the newspeed is maintained for some time, before we decrease it further:
  delay(9);
}
```

this will give you a ramping time of 9ms * 100 loops = 900ms
and a start speed of 100, and end speed of 0.

if you want to continue at full speed between the loops, you can simply add a delay in between them:

```
for(...){} //ramps in (see code block above)
sleep(100) //continue turning for 100ms
for(...){} // ramps out (see code block above)
```

this will be much easier for you to read, if you make functions:

```
void constantRotation(int speed, int time)
{
    motors.setLeftSpeed(-1 * speed);
    motors.setRightSpeed(speed);           
    delay(time)  
}

void rampInRotate(int currentSpeed, int maxSpeed, int timePerRampStep)
{
    for (int speed = currentSpeed; speed < endSpeed; speed++)
    {
         constantRotation(speed, timePerRampStep);
    }
}

void rampOutRotate(int currentSpeed, int minSpeed, int timePerRampStep)
{
    for (int speed = currentSpeed; speed >= minSpeed; speed--)
    {
         constantRotation(speed, timePerRampStep);
    }
}
```

then your code would be something like this:

```
const int speed = 100;
const int rampTime = 300;
const int timeAtFullSpeed = 500;

rampInRotate(0, speed, rampTime);
constantRotation(speed, timeAtFullSpeed);
rampOutRotate(speed, 0, rampTime);
```